# Get the URL of the first image from the product gallery in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gallery, src

How can I get the URL of the first image that is uploaded to the product gallery?

I am not talking about the featured image.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: We need a [mcve] and more details. We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you the first image Url from the product gallery:

```
global $post, $product;

if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product'))
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

    $product = wc_get_product(40);

// Get the array of the gallery attachement IDs
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

if( sizeof($attachment_ids) > 0 ){
    $first_attachment_id = reset($attachment_ids);
    $link = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $first_attachment_id, 'full' )[0];

    // Output
    echo $link;
}
```